# How to interpret a mediation where the a and b paths are significant, but the bootstrapped indirect aXb effect is not

Tags: bootstrap, mediation, pre-post-comparison

I've run a parallel mediation analysis to test for the effects of a poverty simulation intervention. We have theorized that the simulation acts through changes to participants' internal and external attributions for poverty, and our dependent variables of interest is changes to allyship intentions. Specifically:

IV: condition (simulation vs. control)
M1: changes to internal attributions for poverty
M2: changes to external attributions for poverty
DV: changes to allyship intentions (i.e. volunteering on behalf of those in poverty)

PROCESS model 4 was used to run the analysis, 5000 bootstrap samples were drawn to estimate 95% percentile boostrapped CIs, and residualized change scores for M1, M2 and the DV were used as the changes scores in this analysis.

From this analysis, the following results were obtained:

1. Condition significantly predicted M1 (internal attribution) change scores; **a = -0.28, p = .015, 95% CI [-0.505, -0.056]**
2. M1 change scores significantly predicted DV (allyship intention) change scores; **b = -0.10, p = 0.02, 95% CI [-0.177, -0.017]**
3. No significant indirect effect (as determined by bootstrap estimates) was observed; **95% CI for indirect effect ab [-0.010, 0.078]**

How should this result be interpreted? The significant a/b paths but non-significant ab 95% CI seem to be inconsistent results, so I'm not 100% sure how these results should be reported, nor if these results do (or don't) provide support for a mediated effect. Furthermore, is there any writing/resources that provide potential explanations for this pattern of results?

Thank you in advance for your help!